# SciPy Pearsonr p-value is returning value greater than 1

Tags: python, pandas, pearson-correlation

I am using pearsonr to get statistical significance on some data. Below is the code I am using and also the output. The second value is the pvalue and should be between 0 and 1, so I'm confused as to how I am getting otherwise. tis is also the case on other values with very high correlations.

```
stats.pearsonr(dataset['Vertical Velocity'],dataset['Drop Height'])
(-0.9944267653880902, 4.500312000521201e-16)
```

Comment: Could you add an extract of the dataset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: e-16 is the representation of exponential. In this case your number is to the MINUS 16, therefore your number is between 0-1.

```
4.500312000521201e-16 = 0.0000000000000004500312000521201
```